# Add multiple-line legend entry to a pgf-pie chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

I've got a `pgf-pie` chart with a legend. One of the entries is too long to fit on the page and regular LaTeX line-breaking commands don't seem to work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, 12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[sum=auto,text=legend]{52/blah, 36/{blah blah}, 18/{blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Can the legend entry be somehow broken into two lines?

Comment: Well, you could do `18/\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah\\blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah\end{tabular}}`, but it doesn't work that well because of how the legend is built.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, quite rude solution for this particular case. It works only if multi-line text is in the last legend line.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, 
                positioning, 
                shadows}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    pie-label/.style = {text width=54mm, align=left, 
                        anchor=north west, inner xsep=0pt}
                    ]
\pie[sum=auto,text=legend]{52/blah, 36/{blah blah}, 
                           18/{\tikz[baseline=4\baselineskip]\node[pie-label]
                                                {blah blah blah blah blah
                                                blah blah blah blah blah blah
                                                blah blah blah blah blah blah
                                                blah blah blah blah blah blah
                                                blah blah blah blah blah};}
                           }
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But it only works in the case of the final pie slice, no? (and I'm guessing the `stackengine` is vestigial?)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, you are right. In the first I try with `stackengine` (but didn't succeed) and then forgot to remove it from preamble.

Comment: I was about 3 minutes behind you.  I could sort of get it to work with `\strut\smash{\Longunderstack[l]{...}}`, but even then the alignment was not quite right.